# I need to show a msgbox and exit sub if the cells contain anything other than numbers. Right now it gives a blank

Tags: vba, excel

'This code needs to throw an error message if the cells contain any charactar

If Range("i10") <> "" And Range("i10").Value <= 0.25 Then

```
            Range("i10").Copy Range("K22")
            Range("K22").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            Ws.Cells(22, 11).Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous

    ElseIf Range("i10") <> "" And Range("K22").Value > 0.5 Then
            Range("i10").Copy Range("K22")
            Range("K22").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Ws.Cells(22, 11).Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
    Else

    If Range("i10") <> "" And Range("i10").Value > 0.25 And Range("i10").Value <= 0.5 Then
        Range("i10").Copy Range("K22")
        Range("K22").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Ws.Cells(22, 11).Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous

    End If
  End If
```

Comment: Is `ElseIf Range("i10") <> "" And Range("K22").Value > 0.5 Then` correct? It doesn't follow the same pattern as other criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Try IsNumeric which is true for blanks or numbers/dates.

```
if not isnumeric(Range("i10")) then
    msgbox "something"
    exit sub
end if
If Range("i10") <> "" And Range("i10").Value <= 0.25 Then
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also how can i get the code to say something like "The error is in cell C8" etc. So i need to know the cell number basically

Comment: @DevDeb If you're only using hard-coded ranges, than you can simply adjust the msgbox string for each If-statement.